# Primefaces: how to build primefaces.jar only

Tags: maven, primefaces

PrimeFaces: how to build primefaces.jar only without running tests, building docs, etc.

Need to quick check its changes with our app.

```sh
mvn install
```

Will do everything.

Answer (score 2):

With PrimeFaces 12 a `quick` profile was introduced:

```xml
<!-- Quick build for developers which skips many build steps for speed -->
<profile>
    <id>quick</id>
    <properties>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
        <maven.javadoc.skip>true</maven.javadoc.skip>
        <maven.source.skip>true</maven.source.skip>
        <checkstyle.skip>true</checkstyle.skip>
        <license.skipCheckLicense>true</license.skipCheckLicense>
        <license.skipAddThirdParty>true</license.skipAddThirdParty>
        <license.skipAggregateDownloadLicenses>true</license.skipAggregateDownloadLicenses>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

Use with the profile attribute, like:

```sh
mvn clean install -Pquick
```

See https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/8562